# Python requests module timeouts with every https proxy and uses my real ip with http proxies

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, urllib

Basically i get this error with every single https proxy I've tried on every website.

Code:

```
import requests
endpoint = 'https://ipinfo.io/json'
proxies = {'http':'http://45.167.95.184:8085','https':'https://45.167.95.184:8085'}
r = requests.get(endpoint,proxies=proxies,timeout=10)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    r = requests.get(endpoint,proxies=proxies,timeout=10)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 507, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ipinfo.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FDCFB9E6A0>, 'Connection to 45.167.95.184 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))
```

And when I only use http

```
import requests
endpoint = 'https://ipinfo.io/json'
proxies = {'http':'http://45.167.95.184:8085'}
r = requests.get(endpoint,proxies=proxies,timeout=10)
```

The request is sent but websites that return public ips show my real ip. Both requests (2.27.1) and urllib3 (1.26.8) are update to their lastest versions, what could the issue be?

Comment: Something wrong with your proxy config, try using the same http URL for your https proxy: `proxies = {'https': 'http://45.167.95.184:8085', ...}`

Comment: In your second example the proxy is irrelevant because your URL protocol is https

Comment: @OlvinRoght yeah you are right, if I change my URL protocol to http i get a timeout just like the first example